# Can you help me see if I have an old Bitcoin account?

Tags: blockchain, wallet, address, security-key

I set up an crypto account & had different coins in it, but the computer died, updated to a current machine. Have also changed from AOL to Gmail, that was around 98 or 99, if that gives you any idea how long ago this was. Any info or direction would be appreciated. I do not know where or who to speak to see if I had a Bitcoin Acct. or a ledger, wallet or if it was thru Bitcoin? I don't even remember my AOL address, & they are no help? I was going to get back into it & thought maybe I could use the old account? Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Do you remember writing down any kind of information, like 12 or 24 random looking words (or any other information regarding your bitcoin/crypto accounts)?

As @chytrik mentioned, there was no bitcoin or "crypto" (in the sense which the word is used nowadays) before 2009, and wallets that were able to store other cryptos besides bitcoin came into existence only a few years after that.

So what happened in 98/99 shouldn't be of any importance. Perhaps you are conflating something else with "crypto"?

In any case, if you think you might have had a bitcoin wallet, figuring out what kind of wallet/account you used would be a first step, and if you have any other kind of written down information would be very helpful as well (DO NOT SHARE THE ACTUAL CONTENT OF SUCH INFORMATION WITH ANYONE, in case you find it).